# How do I make maildrop not silently drop all mail?

Tags: email, mbox

I'd like to try out maildrop instead of procmail because I'm new to mail filtering and want to avoid accidentally not getting mail.  Putting `|maildrop` in my `$HOME/.forward` results in mail not making it to my `$MAIL` and worse, it doesn't bounce.  It just disappears into the ether.  I'm okay with the limited number of examples of maildrop syntax, but I don't see any howtos explaining how to start using it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try if the maildrop filter is configured corretly: `echo | maildrop .mailfilter`

And do not forget that the `.mailfilter` should have minimal rights: `chmod 600 .mailfilter` (this would also be alerted if you try the first command).